# Understanding operation overloading inside singleton pattern

Tags: c++, singleton, operator-overloading

I have a header file of a Class called Serial: serial.h

Inside this header file I have the following kind of operation overloading:

```
private:
    ...
    Serial & operator = (const Serial &);
```

I know that this is part of the singleton pattern like [here](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B-Programmierung:_Entwurfsmuster:_Singleton#Normal_.28Stack.29)

I also [looked up](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) operation overloading and found the following example of the assignment operator:

```
void operator=(const Distance &D )
```

But what does the "&" mean an how does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the operator overloading and the ampersand have nothing to do with Singleton directly. The ampersand just denotes that the operator takes a reference instead of a copy of the other Serial and returns a reference to a Serial (and again not a copy).

In singletons this is important, but you can (and should) use it without singletons as well.

Comment: So `Serial operator = (const Serial);` would give a constant copy of a Serial object ?

AND Does it make a difference if I would write:
`Serial &operator = (const Serial &);` OR `Serial& operator = (const Serial &);` OR `Serial &operator = (const Serial&);` OR `Serial& operator = (const Serial&);` ?

Comment: `Serial operator= (const Serial)` would take a constant copy of a Serial and return a non-constant Serial object. The return value might be copied or not, depending on your implementation and the compiler optimizations, however it is an rvalue instead of an lvalue, so something like `serial1 = serial2 = serial3` would become invalid. Best is you follow the duplicate link that  πάντα ῥεῖ provided, everything is explained in detail there. The placement of whitespaces does not change anything here.